# How do I use electron-compile?

Tags: ecmascript-6, electron, babeljs

I'm having trouble with [electron-compile](https://github.com/electron/electron-compile).

The docs state

> How does it work? (Easiest Way)
>
> Change your reference to `electron-prebuilt` to `electron-prebuilt-compile`. Tada! You did it.

What reference, where? You can't be talking about `package.json`?

I've always run electron using `supervisor -x "electron" -i "./" .`

What am I completely missing / what should be the contents of my pull request to make this clearer?

I've installed `electron-compile` with `npm i electron-compile --save-dev`

I'd like to have es2015/jsx precompiled to es5, so that I can run a react application in electron. `electron-compile` appears to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install Electron as a dev reference in package.json, yes:

`npm install --save-dev electron-prebuilt-compile`

Don't install Electron as a global because then other people have to set stuff up to run your app (i.e. they now have to micromanage which version of Electron they have installed globally)

Comment: I don't have it installed globally, I just roam around with `node_modules/.bin` in my path, but thanks because I had completely forgotten that I did this (possibly a reason not to do it).

Answer (score 3):

With the recent versions (electron 1.3.5), I was unable to get `electron-prebuilt-compile` working, well it works for development but packaging for production has no real working examples.

It seems the compiling and packaging needs to be done manually, so in case anyone needs a working example, it's [here](https://github.com/buz-zard/random/tree/master/electron-compile-1). Hope to save someone some time and pain.